# Can I define any route without callback function in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

To register a route, I specify the route in `web.php` in following way,

```
Route::get($uri, $callback)->name($name);
```

Is there any way to do this without any specific callback function?

I am building a laravel website but some portion are made with perl. I need to submit a form to a url where the perl code takes over. However, as the form is used in many places I want to use the `$name` part as form action inside my front end codes.

Essentially what I want is something like this,

```
Route::get('cgi-bin/route_to_perl_program.cgi', "DO NOTHING. LET PERL DO IT JOB")->name($url_name);
```

Comment: if you put the file `cgi-bin/route_to_perl_program.cgi` in your `public` folder then it should work. Otherwise if the file is not found then the rewrite rules will run `index.php` which does the routing

Comment: This is really something you should handle in your web server/.htaccess configuration, instead of after the web server has already routed the request to PHP.

Comment: I can access the program. But Is there a way to use the name property. As I need to put the route in various blade files. And I really want to use something like action = {{ route('perl_form') }}.

Comment: Was going to put pretty much @deceze said. You need to configure your server so requests don’t hit Laravel _at all_.

Answer (score 1):

If you not to define any `$callback` function,there is no need to define a route in `web.php`. As you want to use `route('name')` to produce that `url` in all your blade file,there is an **alternative**. You need to add this line of code in your **`config/app.php`** as follows:

```
perl_url => 'cgi-bin/route_to_perl_program.cgi',
```

And use them in your blade like as

```
<a href="{{ config('app.perl_url')}}">link text</a>
```

> This is not your answer,this might be a solution of your specific
>   need.

In your `$callback` function to run a command to execute your `perl` file and get back the output and return that output as a `response`.,e.g:

```
.....
$yourPerlOutPut = exec('perl  ~/your/path/yourfile.pl'); 
return response($yourPerlOutPut);
```

> **[exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)** executes the given **command**.

Comment: This is actually helpful. I will try it.

Comment: added something new,this might be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `route_to_perl_program.cgi` file in `public` folder and access `yourdomain.com/route_to_perl_program.cgi`. It will run. You need not put it the route.

Or try something like the following

```
Route::get('cgi-bin/route_to_perl_program.cgi', function(){
    exec('cgi-bin/route_to_perl_program.cgi');
})->name($url_name);
```

Comment: I understand that. However, I need to put the route in various blade files. And I really want to use something like action = {{ route('perl_form') }}